# Find out if Any is of a unspecified Type

Tags: swift

I want to pass a object and a Type to a method and find out of the object is of the passed in Type. I have it working for AnyObject i think. But Any can be also Strcuts, Strings, Doubles ..

My solution with AnyObject looks like this:

```
class AClass {

}

class BClass {

}
class TypeCheck {
    var type : AnyObject.Type;
    init( type: AnyObject.Type ) {
        self.type = type;
    }
    func isOfType( object: AnyObject ) -> Bool {
        return self.type === object.dynamicType.self ? true : false;
    }
}

var typeCheck = TypeCheck( type: AClass.self );
var a = AClass();
var b = BClass();
println( "Object \(a) is of checked Class: \(typeCheck.isOfType(a))" );//true
println( "Object \(b) is of checked Class: \(typeCheck.isOfType(b))" );//false
```

As like in this example with TypeCheck.type i need to store the Type i want to check against. Is there any Solution for this? All i found were solutions with specific types or only for Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this more simply with generics:

```
import UIKit

class AClass {

}

class BClass {

}


class TypeCheck<T> {
   func isOfType<U>(arg: U) -> Bool {
        return arg is T
    }

}

var typeCheck = TypeCheck<AClass>();
var a = AClass();
var b = BClass();

println( "Object \(a) is of checked Class: \(typeCheck.isOfType(a))" );//true
println( "Object \(b) is of checked Class: \(typeCheck.isOfType(b))" );//false
```

Comment: Well that seems to work with types which are not objects which is great. I have to admit that i have to wrap my head around how it realy works. How would that look like if we would pass both Type and object/value as an argument? I think that could help me alot to understand the logic or is that not possible this way? I specially fall over the <U> ..